# Artifactory Rest API anonymous access with listparameter

Tags: artifactory

On our Artifactory Server we have a repository of the type Generic.
And it is configured to allow anonymous access.

For the rest api we now observed this behaviour:

This call is working:
https://artifactory/artifactory/api/storage/compiler-generic-release/aspl/winlibs

But for this call it requires Authentication:
https://artifactory/artifactory/api/storage/compiler-generic-release/aspl/winlibs?list&deep=1

Response is:
status  403
message "This resource is available to authenticated users only."

Is there a way to also allow anonymous access for the second call?

Thanks for any feedback
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As desribed in JFrog Wiki https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/file-list, this API execution requires privileged access and the access is not extended to the anonymous users.

```
Notes: Requires Artifactory Pro

Security: Requires a non-anonymous privileged user.

Usage:
GET /api/storage/{repoKey}/{folder-path}?list[&deep=0/1][&depth=n][&listFolders=0/1][&mdTimestamps=0/1][&includeRootPath=0/1]

Produces: application/json (application.vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.storage.FileList+json)
```